# $.get() troubles before submitting page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Think a shopping basket with some "goods" in it.
I have a `<li>` list of elements and each of them has a field containing a number - the amount.

Conceptually this is what i want: When the user presses a button, i loop through each `<li>` element picking the amount. Then i do a $.Get() to call the server with the goods id + the amount to check if the store has enough of the particular item.  The server replies either True og False.
This reply is temporary stored in a html field.
Now after the looping is done, i check if there were a False reply on any of the goods.
If so i highlight the "false" items. Or else i simply submit.

OK, the problem is that my code seams to continue past my $.get() call-back function, so the final check to see if any false was returned is evaluated before the $.get() actually receives a result from the server.
Anyway this is what i think is happening...

Now lets look at some code:

```
var tmp = new Array();
var id = '';
var c = '';
var n = 0;
var z=0;
$('#basket').find('li.list').each(function() {
c = $(this).find('input.fldamount').val();  // this is the amount field
id = $(this).attr('id');  // this is the id no of the item
$.get('./(RPC)?OpenAgent&cmd=movewhcheckamount&unid='+id+'&count='+c, function(data) {
    $('#RPCResult').val(data);  // i store the returned value in a html field
    if ( $('#RPCResult').val() == "true" ) {
      tmp.push( id+'|'+c );  // if true is returned, i push the id & amount to an array
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('red');  // else i tag the item
      n=n+1;  // and then increment a counter
    }
} );  // $('#basket')

var t = window.setTimeout( function() {
  if (tmp.length > 0 && n == 0)  {  // if i got items in the array AND my false counter is zero
    $('#SelectedArtikler').val( tmp.join(";") );  // then i store the array as text in a field
    document._FlyttArtikel.submit();  // and submit
  } else if (n > 0) {
    // show a popup
    alert("You're trying to move more items than exists...");
  } else {
    alert("ops, nothing to move...");  // should never end up here...
  }
}, 1000);
window.clearTimeout(t);
```

As you can see, i have tried to counter-act the code running past my call-back function with a setTimeout, so that i basically wait a sec to give the server time to respond.
I did have another loop around the setTimeout the continued as long as my #RPCResult field was empty, but that resulted in an infinite loop.

I have the #RPCResult field visible so i can see what happens and what i see is that the popup "You're trying to move more items..." is shown and RIGTH AFTER i press ok on that popup THEN the #RPCResult field gets the result true/false.

I now some of the code can be optimized but what i'm interested in right now is getting the $.get() result in a proper fashion.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: 1st I don't want to thread you, but why didn't put the funtion body into an extra function at method .setTimeout(). The code would be defnitly better to read.

Comment: You're right, but this is a rough code still in development ;-)

Comment: :-), but you do a favour for your self, if you write a clean code. Prevents mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to place the code that's going to run when all the "$.get()" calls are finished **inside** the callback routine. That's the only place where you can be sure that you've actually gotten the server response(s).  Keep a counter of how many calls have returned, and when the counter increments up to be equal to the total number of items, then you know that all of the responses are available.

Thus:

```
var basketSize = $('#basket').find('li.list').length, completed = 0;
```

gives you the number of items and initializes the counter. Inside the callback function passed to "$.get()" you can then do something like this:

```
  if (++completed === basketSize) {
    // code currently in the "setTimeout()" callback
  }
```

Your code already appears to be doing some of this work (the "n" variable that you increment).

Now, that said, I'll also note that it's quite crazy to perform separate HTTP transactions for each of your "items".  You should bundle them all up into **one** HTTP request that returns a list of answers.

Also, there's really no point at all in storing the response to the "$.get()" in that "RPCresult" field; just examine the value of "data", since nothing ever looks at "RPCresult" again anyway.

Comment: Ah, good point!  I'll try this when i get home...
About the HTTP transactions, strictly speaking you're right.
But i don't expect more than max 10 items in the basket.
And last the RPCResult field were just made to make the response visible while developing ;-)
Thank you for spending time on this, i'll get back with my result later!

Comment: Well the thing is that most of the time taken up by the HTTP transaction will stem from the latencies involved, so doing 10 separate requests will very likely take almost 10 times as long as doing just one.